# OpenGL multiple subwindow problems

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glut

I am having a problem with my GL code. I'm running on an Ubuntu 12.10 platform and I'm trying to render vertex array data in two sub windows I've created. I create a main window and then right after that two subwindows.

I am rendering the vertex data to both subwindows but the problem is, the vertex data is only rendered to the very last subwindow declared. The other subwindow just remains black.

These are the display callback functions:

```
void display1( void )
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 59);   

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void display2( void )
{

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );     // clear the window
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 59);       
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To render into another window or subwindow, you need to set it as active with [glutSetWindow](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node18.html).

It depends from where you issue image update, and that is where you set the active window. For example, if you do it from a reshape function, you need to do it there :

```
void Reshape1( int width, int height )
{
  // activate sub-window 1
  glutSetWindow(subWin1);
  // ...
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
void Reshape2( int width, int height )
{
  // activate sub-window 2
  glutSetWindow(subWin2);
  // ...
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem nor did it really change anything with the state of the program from what I could observe,

Comment: @user1610329 Of course it changed. Every sub-window has it's own opengl context. The fact that you do not observe difference indicates you may have other problems.